# how can i get mean value of str type in a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame from pandas:

i want to get a mean value of "stop_duration" for each "violation_raw".
How can i do it if column "stop_duration" is object type

```
df = enter code herepd.read_csv('police.csv', parse_dates=['stop_date'])
df[['stop_date', 'violation_raw','stop_duration']]
```

My table:

[the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSP8v.jpg)

Comment: You should provide a full text based input output example, especially since the logic of averaging is ambiguous in your case

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function to convert object to datetime. Also specifying a format to match your data.

```
import pandas as pd    
df["column"] = pd.to_datetime(df["column"], format="%M-%S Min")
```